# What's the difference between "dataproc" and "dataprocpb" packages in Google Cloud Client Libraries for Go?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

While working on Dataproc's Client Library for Go, I noticed that there are two packages [dataproc](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/dataproc/apiv1#NewBatchControllerClient) and [dataprocpb](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/dataproc/apiv1/dataprocpb#NewBatchControllerClient). Dataproc package seems to be referencing some objects defined in dataprocpb.

I don't understand the reason why we have these two separate modules. How are they different and which one should we use when using Google Cloud Client Libraries for Go? Some functions seem to appear in both modules.

I noticed that other Google Cloud Client Libraries are also structured similarly. For example, Spanner has [spannerpb](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/spanner@v1.44.0/apiv1/spannerpb). Is this a common structure for Go in general or is this specific for these libraries? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/dataproc/latest/apiv1) package in google-cloud-go is the standard high level package which is used to interact with Google's Dataproc service using the go client.

`pb` in [Dataprocpb](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/dataproc/latest/apiv1/dataprocpb) package refers to *protobuf*. Hence, Dataprocpb package provides Go bindings to interact with Dataproc API's protobuf messages. This package is generally used when you need to interact with the API in a more customized way.

So, the main difference lies in how packages are interacting with the product ie. Dataproc service. Likewise other products as you mentioned also have pb packages.